# How to speedup the website which uses big gif images?

Tags: express, compression, gzip

I have a website which is in expressjs and i want to speed up it. Now it is taking a lot of time to load.

In this site there are 4 gif images which has around 7mb sizes each!.

I tried the gif lazy loading method to speed up it.It seems not working.I use express,nodejs and it is a simple html5 website.

The index.js as follows:

```
var compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()



app.use(compression());


// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// Handles all routes so you do not get a not found error
app.get('*', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port" + port)
```

How can i speed up my website?

Url : `swoo.tv`

Comment: How did you create the gifs? Do you have source files? Your gifs have quite a lot of dithering/noise, which pretty much prevents any smarter optimization methods. They could be significantly smaller if some different creation/optimization methods are used, but it's difficult to do anything with these images now without affecting the quality, because of noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use [compression middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) to compress your server responses:

example

```
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// compress responses
app.use(compression());
```

2. cache your static files:

example

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.match(/^\/(css|js|img|font|gif)\/.+/)) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=3600'))
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Where will i add the #2 ? i'm sorry i am new to expressjs.I updated my question.

Comment: you just add it to your main .js server file (usually app.js)

Comment: While these are good things to have, they won't really solve ops problem. Compressing image files is not very effective.

Comment: It depends on the image. On the over side, client caching in this case is rock solid